# is Custom Setting by pass validation visibility to different transaction?

Tags: validation-rule, customsetting

We use custom setting to by pass validation rule.We use it alot , even in some of batch job when we to update the record.

A concern that in scenario whereby two transactions happen and one is updating the custom setting value will it visible to another transaction?I am sure this will not happen for custom object, but will it happen for custom setting.If batch job update the custom setting to true , meanwhile user is updating the record in user interface will it see the custom setting value as true?

I hope I am asking correctly.

Comment: yes there are chances,when you batch updates the value and before you reset it user tries to create record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ques: If batch job update the custom setting to true , meanwhile user is updating the record in user interface will it see the custom setting value as true?

Until the transaction for updating the Custom settings record is committed, it will not get effected. So, the user is updating the record in user interface will see as **False**.

Comment: So I should feel safe using the same custom setting accross application ,correct?

Comment: yes, but in same org